# git merge requests without merge confict

Tags: git

I am changing a file in my branch (dev) and trying send merge request to master branch. But it is impossible to achieve this without merge conflict.

How can it possible to send merge request without conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should manually resolve conflicts. This is [GitHub's guide](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/) and [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts).

Before sending the PR, fetch code from master and merge it with your branch. If there are conflicts, resolve them, commit and push.

Answer (score 0):

There are bound to be some Files and Packages that lead to merging Conflict.
Go to the Command Prompt and see what is causing the Merg conflict in your Repository using-

**git status**

You will see the conflicting Lines between these
<<<<<<< HEAD
.
.
. 
.>>>>>>

Delete or modify them to resolve your conflict

If you are using Intellij I will suggest resetting the Head of your Directory.
It may work. Use this reference for more Information
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-conflicts.html

Answer (score 0):

What error message did you get from git? Usually means there's changes to a certain file in both versions and git doesn't know which version is correct. The error message will tell you which file is causing the conflict.